# the query failed to parse.The batch could not be analyzed because of compile errors in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am getting the following error in SSIS because of that my package is getting failed. I have built the package for Audit purpose for which I am passing both system & user variables. My query is like this.

```
insert into AuditInfo
(
    PackageName
    , PackageId
    , PacakgeVersion
    , StartTime
    , WorkflowStatus
    , rowcounts
)
values
(
?,?,?,?,?,?
)
```

[image]

Parameter mapping details:

[image]

Error of query:

[image]

Please help me how to resolve the following issue.

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into AuditInfo
>   (PackageName, PackageId...failed with the following error: "An error
>   occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type
>   (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly,
>   or connection not established correctly.

Comment: What is the datatype of the user variable RowCount?

Comment: @DEEPAKLAKHOTIA Int is the datatype

Comment: How are you calculating row count?

Comment: Add a screenshot of the General tab of your Execute SQL Task properties.   What is the connection type used by the Task?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your connection type is OLE DB.

This means that on the Parameter Mapping tab, the Parameter Name values are integers, which you used, but they are zero-based.   Meaning the first parameter in the query should be named "0", the next parameter should be "1", etc.

You started with the first parameter as "1", so your parameters are not mapping correctly, and you're getting the error.

[Here's the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you sir  for the documentation link & your help.